# ¿Cuál es el significado de agazapar?

Tags: vocabulario

Durante  mis 25 años de vida, pasados entre Cuba, Ecuador, y los Estados Unidos no he visto ni leído la palabra "agazapado" que hoy encontré en un libro. ¿Ésta es una palabra común en latinoamérica?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En la rae hay la definición:

> agazapar.
>
> (De gazapo).
>
> 1. tr. coloq. p. us. Agarrar, coger o prender a alguien.
> 2. prnl. Esconderse, ocultarse, estar al acecho.
> 3. prnl. coloq. Agacharse, encogiendo el cuerpo contra la tierra, como lo hace el gazapo cuando quiere ocultarse de quienes le persiguen.

Su uso en latinoamérica se acerca a la segunda definición, en otra entrada de la RAE

> agazapado 
>    ( de gazapo)
>   1. adj. Costa Rica. hipócrita.

[Referencia: RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/drae/srv/search?val=agazapada)

En Venezuela:

> Persona que aparenta ser comportada y dócil, que no parte ni un plato. Pero es todo lo contrario. Sinónimo de morronga, mosquita muerta.

[Referencia: asihablamos](http://www.asihablamos.com/word/palabra/Agazapado.php)

Comment: En Argentina la palabra es de uso común, pero sólo en las acepciones 2 y 3 de la RAE. Yo no conocía la 1.

Answer (score 1):

En español de España el uso más común de Agazaparse (nótese el pronominal) es la segunda acepción del DRAE: Esconderse, ocultarse, estar al acecho.